# jQuery/JavaScript if statement for two toggles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, toggle

I have two toggles (toggle-1 and toggle-2) with different contents in a header. I would like to prevent the user to have both toggles active simultaneously (otherwise they overlap).

In the code below I tried to use if statements to hide one of the toggles if the other is already opened but it does not work.

Ideally, what I would like to happen is that if toggle-1 is active and the user clicks on toggle-2, then toggle-1 would come back to its original state and toggle-2 would be now active. The same the other way around.

I am not familiar with JavaScript yet and I'd really appreciate if you could tell me what I have done wrong and how it should be done to have my ideal result

Here's the link to my CodePen if you find it easier:
https://codepen.io/fergos2/pen/NWWxgEp

```js
var myToggle

var oneToggle = $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggle-1').click(function() {
    $('.toggle-1').toggleClass('active')
    $('.toggle-1-content').toggleClass('active')
  })
})

var twoToggle = $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggle-2').click(function() {
    $('.toggle-2').toggleClass('active')
    $('.toggle-2-content').toggleClass('active')
  })
})

if (myToggle == oneToggle) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('toggle-2-content').hide();
  })
} else if (myToggle == twoToggle) {
  $('toggle-1-content').hide();
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: pink;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.toggle-1,
.toggle-2 {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px;
}

.toggle-1.active,
.toggle-2.active {
  background-color: red;
}

.toggle-1-content,
.toggle-2-content {
  display: none;
}

.toggle-1-content.active,
.toggle-2-content.active {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
}

.toggle-1-content.active {
  left: 0;
}

.toggle-2-content.active {
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="toggle-1">1</div>
    <div class="toggle-1-content">
      <p>Some content 1</p>
    </div>

    <div class="toggle-2">2</div>
    <div class="toggle-2-content">
      <p>Some content 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code:

```html
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggle-1').click(function() {
    if ($('.toggle-2').hasClass('active')) {
      // remove toggle-2 active classes
      $('.toggle-2').removeClass('active');
      $('.toggle-2-content').removeClass('active');
    }
    
    $('.toggle-1').toggleClass('active');
    $('.toggle-1-content').toggleClass('active');
  });
  
  $('.toggle-2').click(function() {
    if ($('.toggle-1').hasClass('active')) {
      // remove toggle-1 active classes
      $('.toggle-1').removeClass('active');
      $('.toggle-1-content').removeClass('active');
    }
    
    $('.toggle-2').toggleClass('active');
    $('.toggle-2-content').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

Here is [the link](https://codepen.io/kuehlr92/pen/KKKVvyx) to my working version.

A few things to keep in mind:

1. You don't need to call `$(document).ready()` multiple times. There's just no reason to call it multiple times on a single page as the event is only fired once.
2. You need to keep track of state somehow; hence the `if ($('el').hasClass('classname'))` syntax. Once you handle that properly, it's easy to ensure that each element is 'reset' to its original state when the other is clicked.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Please post code IN the answer. Click edit and then `[<>]` snippet editor

Comment: Also DRY, Don't repeat yourself

Answer (score 1):

Several issues.

Please study the code below

- too many $(document.ready... and no need to store the result of such a statement
- Using a data-attribute and a common class, shortens the code a lot. DRY Don't repeat yourself
- I simplified the content containers CSS too

```js
$(function() { // on page load
  $('.toggle').on("click", function() { // any of the toggles
    const $wrapper = $(this).closest(".wrapper");
    const id = $(this).data("id");

    $(this).toggleClass('active');      // toggle clicked div 
    const show = $(this).is(".active"); // is it active after we toggled?

    $wrapper
      .find(".toggle")        // find all toggles
      .not(this)              // exclude the one we clicked
      .removeClass("active"); // remove class

    $wrapper.find(".content").hide(); // hide any content divs

    $("#" + id).toggle(show); // show the one belonging to the clicked toggle
  })
})
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: pink;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.toggle {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px;
}

.active {
  background-color: red;
}

.content {
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
}

#div1 {
  left: 0;
}

#div2 {
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="toggle" data-id="div1">1</div>
    <div id="div1" class="content">
      <p>Some content 1</p>
    </div>

    <div class="toggle" data-id="div2">2</div>
    <div id="div2" class="content">
      <p>Some content 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`toggleClass` accepts a second boolean parameter that forces the type of toggle, on or off. More than that you can also target multiple elements with a single jQuery call, so use that to your advantage since the classes applied have the same name.

So you could simplify your code to

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggle-1').click(function() {
    $('.toggle-1, .toggle-1-content').toggleClass('active');
    $('.toggle-2, .toggle-2-content').toggleClass('active', false)
  })

  $('.toggle-2').click(function() {
    $('.toggle-2, .toggle-2-content').toggleClass('active');
    $('.toggle-1, .toggle-1-content').toggleClass('active', false)
  })
})
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: pink;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.toggle-1,
.toggle-2 {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 10px;
}

.toggle-1.active,
.toggle-2.active {
  background-color: red;
}

.toggle-1-content,
.toggle-2-content {
  display: none;
}

.toggle-1-content.active,
.toggle-2-content.active {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
}

.toggle-1-content.active {
  left: 0;
}

.toggle-2-content.active {
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="toggle-1">1</div>
    <div class="toggle-1-content">
      <p>Some content 1</p>
    </div>

    <div class="toggle-2">2</div>
    <div class="toggle-2-content">
      <p>Some content 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the method "removeClass" to remove the active class from the other toggle

```
var oneToggle = $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".toggle-1").click(function() {
        $(".toggle-1").toggleClass("active")
        $(".toggle-1-content").toggleClass("active")
        $(".toggle-2").removeClass("active")
        $(".toggle-2-content").removeClass("active")
    })
})

var twoToggle = $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".toggle-2").click(function() {
        $(".toggle-1").removeClass("active")
        $(".toggle-1-content").removeClass("active")
        $(".toggle-2").toggleClass("active")
        $(".toggle-2-content").toggleClass("active")
    })
})
```

Comment: When down voting an answer it would be very helpful to provide the reason as well in the comment. This will allow the answerer to improve and provide better answers in the future